# Echo function displays on separate html page, can I possibly echo to a certain element by ID like JS? Alternative solutions?

Tags: php, html

INEXPERIANCED WITH PHP! SORRY FOR STUPID QUESTION!

My php email form submit is functioning as intended other than the success message. When I call my php from my form submit button the email sends correctly however the "echo "Thank You!" message at the end of the code displays on a new plaintext page ( only thing displayed is "Thank You!" ) with the slug "www.website.com/mail.php" ( the name of the php file ).

I understand this is possibly because I'm calling a separate file instead of running the php within the html document however I was hoping I wouldn't need to have my php in the same document, i'd rather keep it tidy and easier to work on in the future.

I have a few ideas as a workaround -

- Instead of using echo I could call a seperate JS script which finds the tag with ID I wish to display the sucess message on.
- Unsure if this would work but I could assign a global variable to have the sucess message then have php within my html which echos the variable.
- Putting the PHP in the html ( as said above )
- Instead using an alert if php is capable of that

However surely there is a better way of doing this? I cannot seem to find anyone who can help, believe me when I say I've googled so many times for a solution. Is my second solution the proper way? How should I be doing this "properly"?

Mail.php:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "ddddn@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: contact@sdasdsdaT.com \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="php/mail.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Your Name</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="Name input feild" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Your Message">Your Message</label>
              <textarea class="form-control messagebox" placeholder="Any and all enquiries are welcome!" name="message" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

Not sure what i'd expect from the php currently there, possibly for the echo message to appear within the tag form tag where the php file is called?

Again, I've really used every resource I have and I'm trying my best here. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: That's because that is all you output. If you want HTML then you'll need to add it. If you want it to appear on the same page you will need to learn about ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the AJAX thing. I'm looking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna explain a bit and help out a little bit so as to leave space for your learning.
So, currently what you are doing is you are calling another page when you submit your form.
When the new page loads you're are displaying "thank you" using PHP.

What I understood from the question is you want to stay on the same page while sending the email and then display the text. For this we have to use AJAX in order to stay and do that job. Now, AJAX would be much easier with JQ, however I am guessing you are only new to this so I am gonna put the code in JS.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="call()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function call(){
    console.log("called");
    var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            var txt = this.responseText;
      if(txt == "true"){
                alert("Thank You");
            }
            else{
                alert("false");
            }
    }
        else{
            console.log(this.status);
        }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "php/mail.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo "true";
?>
```

In this you will be able to display alert on the same page. You can beautify it by using Sweet Alert library if you want. I am guessing you can figure out the integration of your code in this. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response!! I have JQuery but haven't gotten into it yet. I'll try this out once I understand it, thankyou!